# Timestamps on git commits after rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rev-list

I'm trying to undo my bad git practices from times past and in doing so, I want to get a list of commits to specific files, newer than a certain timestamp (older commits to these files were cherry-picked to the master branch, which I now realise was a *very bad* idea, considering that the originating branch was nowhere near finished). Illustrated simplified:

```
A---A1-...-CB1--CB2-...-CBm--A5--A6 | master
 \
  B1--B2--B3-...-Bm-...-Bn          | topic
 \
  B1--B2_3--B4-...-Bn                | topic-R
```

- Commits B1..Bm were cherry-picked into master from the topic branch some time ago, illustrated here as CB1, CB2, etc.
- Work on the files continued in the original topic branch (master branch didn't touch them), here as Bm+1..Bn
- I recently created the topic-R branch as a copy of the topic branch, and interactively rebased it on top of merge-base with master to clean up the history (squash and fixup).

I now want to get a list of commits Bm+1..Bn from topic-R with `git rev-list`. So I found the commit CBm, and in the history (and rev-list output) of topic-R it shows the date I'd expect, some 9 months ago.

```
git rev-list --after "2020-08-07" <A>..topic-R --reverse -- <file list>
```

So I feed this to `rev-list` and surprisingly, I'm getting all the commits, as if the `--after/--since` filter was ignored. Passing `--pretty` to `rev-list` still shows the expected date under *Date* - a date from months ago, when the code was written. But when I pass `--timestamp` to `rev-list`, I see very recent timestamps on *all* of the commits in the list - from when I rebased the topic-R branch merely days ago.

What is going on here? Is there to way to tell `rev-list` to filter by the original timestamp, which is very obviously still available?

I know I can just use the Bm+1's hash from topic-R to limit the listing, but I'm curious what kinds of timestamps git keeps track of and if filtering by the original timestamp is possible.

Comment: By original dates I mean dates when the commit was first made in the topic branch - between 12 a 3 months ago.

That rebasing makes new commits makes sense (they have new hashes), but the original dates are still retained somewhere, as those are still shown in the history of the topic-R (rebased) branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every commit has *two* date-and-time stamps.  One is called the *author date* and one is called the *committer date*.

When you make a new commit in the usual way, using `git commit` and no trickery, both are set to the *same value*.  Git retrieves the current time from your computer clock, and if that's accurate, the new commit's two date-stamps are "now".

When you make a commit using `git cherry-pick` or something that internally uses the cherry-pick machinery (such as `git rebase`), Git normally preserves the *original author* of the commit, and the original author-date.  You become the committer, and "now" is the committer date.

To see *both* time stamps with `git log`, use any of the formatting options that prints both.  The simplest to use is `git log --pretty=fuller`.

The `--since` and `--until` (or `--after` and `--before`) options to `git log` use the *committer* date only.  (I think there should be a way to specify author dates, but there isn't.)